# Javascript nodeValue returns null

Tags: javascript, null, nodevalue

Title should make my problem well described.Here goes my code.

```
<div id="adiv"><text>Some text</text></div>    
<script type="text/javascript">
function vb(){
alert(document.getElementById("adiv").firstChild.nodeValue); //returns null
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="vb();" value="get"/>
```

wheres the problem..?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to get [merged] text content of an element node:

```
function vb(){
var textnode = document.getElementById("adiv").firstChild;
alert(textnode.textContent || textnode.innerText);
}
```

In order to get text content of a text node:

```
function vb(){
alert(document.getElementById("adiv").firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks..actually double firstchild is kinda weird.

Comment: it's not weird... firstChild is <Text> and the firstChild of <Text> is the textnode itself.

Comment: the text inside the node IS the text node. For instance, for a formatted document like

`<foo>\n<bar>baz</bar>\n</foo>`

the childNodes property of the `foo` node returns

`NodeList [ #text "\n", <bar>, #test "\n" ]`

Answer (score 13):

You are missing a firstChild:

```
alert(document.getElementById("adiv").firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

(I know it sounds weird but this is how text nodes work)

Comment: @user1473206 do you have a jsfiddle or similar to test this?

Comment: I have tried this on ie8 and 9, nodeValue returned as Null

Answer (score -2):

`<text>` node is not supported in IE 7.