# Unable to get value of the property 'nodeValue': object is null or undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<script>
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
  else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","Default.xml",false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

 var management=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Management");

document.write("<tr><td>");
document.write(management[i].getElementsByTagName("RepresentativeName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td></tr>");

</script>
```

i am getting it working in other browsers with no value in xml element. but ie throws me the error and doesnt render the UI

Comment: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/a/3977764/2135140 can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add if condition before write it on document.

Try code like this

```
<script>
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
  else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","Default.xml",false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

 var management=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Management");

document.write("<tr><td>");
if(management[i].getElementsByTagName("RepresentativeName")[0].childNodes[0]){
  document.write(management[i].getElementsByTagName("RepresentativeName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}else{
  document.write('');
}
document.write("</td></tr>");

</script>
```

Comment: you mean to say i need to check whether it has a value or not if yes render the data else render ' '. Am i right ?

Comment: i have such a huge xml file. data can be there cannot be there...adding conditions everywhere is a right thing ?

Comment: You need to do so, otherwise it fails every time open with IE

Comment: Did it  Bhavin Solanki. Thanks for the help buddy. Actually your logic met my objective but somewhere in my mind i am not satisfied idk why. anyways thanks a lot

Comment: i appreciate your effort bro...just thinking to which extent i can optimize the code..but your logic was awesome